# Find the value of an input with an addEventListener after the value is changed by a select box

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am trying to use an `eventListener` to check input in an input box (`type="number"`):

```
aE.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  console.log(aE.value);
}
```

But what I really need the `eventListener` to pick up is any change in `value` on the input box. This particular input box has a select where users can choose one of a few numerical options for constants. But the current method of eventListener does not pick up changes in value from that select.

What is the correct syntax to get the value of the input box whenever it changes?

Comment: Worth noting that some browser-specific extensions may not trigger some events

Comment: I tried on a couple of browsers though. Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if *input* listener do exactly you want

Try using *change* | *keypress* | *keydown* | *keyup*

Comment: I tried change... nothing. All the key events require a keyboard input. This is input via a select button and then injected with JS.

Comment: Oh, i misunderstood you i thought you needed listener when the user write on input number. Only to clarify, you have a select and when the user select an option you set the value on input:number, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use change event to get the value.

```
selectEl.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.value);
});
```

[Try this example on codepen](https://codepen.io/tashish_/pen/eYrQXrW?editors=1000)

Comment: This doesn't work in this situation. I already do the change via JS of the value of the input and I can use it in a calculation. But I can't use that change as the eventListener - it doesn't hear anything if I use "change".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `aE` has been defined by some earlier code to resolve from a querySelector.

You would want to listen to a change event since it is coming from a `select` input.  Also, you need to add `target` to get the internal value and return the event, not the element.

```
const aE = document.getElementById('idOfAe');
 
aE.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.value)
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I can change the value of the input via JS but I can't use that new value in the eventListener listening for change. This one ignores all changes in fact.

Comment: @PaulDavis is this an input from a library or framework? Or is it just plain HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my only way around was testing the actual select button as well as the input. So I have multiple eventListeners.

The new one is set up for the `<select>` attribute.

```
selectA.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
console.log(aE.value);
}
```

The original aE listener remains as well. So it's two listeners to do the same job in a sort-of-way.